# EAR deployment in webpshere

Tags: websphere, ear

WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=in BLA WebSphere:blaname=failed to start.

MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=,version=8.5.5.0,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Module not found

Comment: SO, you got an error while deploying an EAR?  What version and edition of WebSphere and what command(s) you were executing when error occurred?  You should examine the server logs/FFDC in the affected server profile and add any additional details from them to your question.

Comment: Websphere 8.5.5 Deploying the Ear through console

Comment: Deploying EJB as webservice using annotationException:com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning SourceId:com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl ProbeId:297 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl@71ff5ca4
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.exception.ConfigurationWarning: Module not found
 at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2189)

Answer (score 0):

Some times deployment is partially done and intallApps folder might be have the Ear package from where Webpshere will try to read while starting the Ear package,